# Visual Studio 2015 C# Interactive window refresh .dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-interactive

I'm using the C# Interactive window to test some of my data processing code, and I want to be able to make a change in the class, recompile, and then test out the changes.

I'm finding that if I recompile the code and then do:

```
#r "c:\Path\To\Reference.dll"
```

It doesn't replace the cached reference.

Is there any way to make a change in the code, recompile, and then run a command in the REPL that reloads the module?

Right now I'm having to run the `#reset` command, but this clears out all of my other session data, which slows down my testing.

Comment: That's how the C# REPL is supposed to work.

Comment: The C# REPL will only clear the cache when I run `#reset`?  There is no other way to override the cache?

Comment: As far as I know. And `csi` doesn't even have the `#clear` command. How would you do that?